# Questions about AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is my understanding correct that there is something wrong with my setup if **my Cognito domain URL leads to a completely blank screen?**

For context this is the actual link that gets hit when I try to log in via Google in my web app:

```
https://https//app-staging.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com
/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code&
client_id=6hc77glg1j5bf77hr7222pe1f9&identity_provider=Google&scope
=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin%20email%20openid%20phone%20
profile&state=VECFZ6rkJppApLs6t7rmvWd6eAsQt733
&code_challenge=OLFasqA8SeKpys2-x9UGSWhU7ejDjLTovIveTaCyIb0&code_challenge_method=S256
```

which leads to a site cannot be reached error.

I guess the primary issue is that I don't get a lot of feedback about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does it really start with `https://https`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Not sure how it's possible since I just generate a Cognito domain in the AWS console...

EDIT: At least I'm getting an error now. An error was encountered with the requested page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, rewrite **https://https//** to **https://**

I tried hitting the URL after the above change, got the same site cannot be reached error.

```
https://app-staging.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code&client_id=6hc77glg1j5bf77hr7222pe1f9&identity_provider=Google&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin%20email%20openid%20phone%20profile&state=VECFZ6rkJppApLs6t7rmvWd6eAsQt733&code_challenge=OLFasqA8SeKpys2-x9UGSWhU7ejDjLTovIveTaCyIb0&code_challenge_method=S256
```

As all the parameters required for the authorization endpoint seems correct, you can just verify again that there are no typing mistakes in base domain.